# What could go wrong with this inlined javascript variable initialization in ASP?

Tags: xss, javascript, asp.net

I am currently reviewing an ASP application where this javascript initialization is used all over the place:

```
const someValue = "<% get_some_value() %>";
```

And this pattern is actually something recommended in some StackOverflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540274/3503855). Now, since this is being passed inside a javascript tag, I wonder what could go wrong if `get_some_value()` is untrusted?

Disclaimer: I am not very familiar with ASP.

Comment: This about what would happen if the ASP get_some_value() function returned the string `"; alert('danger'); //`.  Now, think about what would happen if the string returned by the function were slightly more nefarious than just a javascript alert.

Comment: @mti2935 Yes, I am not too sure how the <% %> tag works. Would it take care of stringifying that payload?

Comment: The `<%` and `%>` tags tell the server to execute the ASP code this is inside these tags.  These tags do not get served by the server (you won't see them on the client side if you view the source of the page).  Hence, they do not do any sort of sanitization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code echoes whatever the function `get_some_data()` returns into the JS code, and send it to the client. (You probably forgot an equal sign in `<%=`.) So if the function returns `"; alert("XSS") //` the client will recieve and run this JS code:

```
const someValue = ""; alert("XSS") //";
```

If the data returned by `get_some_value()` is untrusted - i.e. it could be controlled by an attacker - then this is an XSS vulnerability. An attacker could execute JS in the victims browser, and use it to steal data (including passwords and authentication tokens), make API calls, display incorrect information on your webpate, or just about anything that can be done with JS.

That is a pretty big deal and should be fixed ASAP. But all this is under the assumption that the attacker can control what `get_some_data()` returns. Hopefylly there is some sanitation going on inside that function that prevents an XSS attack.

Comment: I was inspecting someone else's code, and the equal sign `=` was not part of the tag. So what's the semantic difference between the two (`<% %>` and `<%= %>`, and what's the security implications of each?

Comment: `<%= get_some_value() %>` runs `foobar` and outputs the return value. Without the equal sign it just runs the function. For there to be an XSS vulnerability, something has to be outputted. Perhaps some value is outputted inside the function.

Comment: the code I was inspecting does thung a bit differently, and the sanitization is somehow inlined within the function itself. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is essentially inserting the raw value of the output of `get_some_value()` into the script.

If `get_some_value()` is untrusted then the method could gain access to execute malicious script on the site. A lot of sites have protection against foreign script through mechanisms like CORS.  This would bypass those protections. If the site had a lot of endpoints that can be called through JavaScript then it would be potentially pretty problematic.

Depending on the source of the data coming from `get_some_value()` it could allow for users to easily compromise your system by inserting script code into a form field that then gets dropped right into the JavaScript without any validation.

If `get_some_value()` will only ever output data that has been encoded, sanitized, and validated to ensure it cannot exit the quotation marks and do something undesired, the risk might be lower.